# Android device unable to connect wifi

Tags: wifi, android, adb

Though I have specified, key_mgmt as WPA-PSK, the device reads it as none. Is there any problem in device? if yes how can it be rectified.

I also used these commands to give device information about wifi.

```
wpa_cli -p/data/misc/wifi/sockets/ -iwlan0
add_network
set_network 0 auth_alg OPEN
set_network 0 key_mgmt WPA-PSK
set_network 0 ssid "5_18-SS-161-CH"
set_network 0 psk "1234567890"
select_network 0 "5_18-SS-161-CH"
enable_network 0 "5_18-SS-161-CH"
reassociate
```

when i use these commands, android device connects to wifi, but as soon as I rerun when I use the below given command and see network info it reads key_mgmt as none.

```
cat /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

is it possible to give details of the AP permanently, so that the device doesn't forget it at all even after I diable and enable wifi it should remember the same information, using following commands:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
ssid="hdwireless"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
group=TKIP
pairwise=TKIP
proto=WPA
psk="hdwirelesskey"
priority=1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your setup to the `wpa_suppilcant.conf` file using the following command:

```
save_config
```

The command should save your config and return `OK`.